# Android app safety - how to?

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard

Having worked on my app throughout my vacation, I plan to release it. I am using `Reto Meier`'s book as a reference. So far, it only mentioned about `ProGuard` to obfuscate the code.

Being new to releasing Android apps, I would like to know what steps, apart from `ProGuard`, do I have to take to ensure that my app is not pirated.

I know there is nothing called 100% secure but I would like to make my app as difficult to reverse engineer as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you intend to hide. You should think which are your valuable assets in your app. If you are *really* concerned about hiding your code, you should try to put the core logic in the server side when possible.

You can check out [DexGuard](http://www.saikoa.com/dexguard), which is a commercial product from the same company as ProGuard, but offers several more obfuscating features. For an individual developer just starting out it might not be worth it though.

Comment: I was [watching this video](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/202143-eclipse-with-proguard) and it says that configuring `ProGuard` when you have external libraries can be difficult. I do have a few libraries. What more do I need to configure?

Comment: For those JAR dependencies that have already been processed with ProGuard, you should avoid applying ProGuard again. Read [this article](http://www.crashlytics.com/blog/mastering-proguard-for-building-lightweight-android-code/) from Crashlytics that explains this and other useful things. First see if the JAR was processed or not, by reading the author's documentation or looking into the JAR. As for other basic ProGuard configuration, check out the section on developer.android.com.

Comment: The problem with external libraries is that you don't know the code in them, so you could potentially be stripping out or changing things that you shouldn't with ProGuard, such as when using reflection.

Comment: There is no reflection in my code. How would I know that I have stripped code that shouldnt have been stripped?